# Javascript for loop with multiple conditions not working

Tags: javascript

I wanted to write below code with For loop having multiple conditions but it didn't work. Please point the mistake I made.

```js
// Working as expected
bs = [false, true, false];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if (bs[i]) {
    console.log('Hi', i);
  }
}
```

Code that is not working as expected

```js
// Not working as expected
bs = [false, true, false];
for (let i = 0; i < 3 && bs[i]; i++) {
  console.log('Hi', i);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second for loop stops the moment its condition evaluates to false. It's not like it *skips* a false value.

Since the first value in the array in `false`, the for loop doesn't run its body once.

Answer (score 1):

The entire for loop is exiting as the exit condition is evaluated to `false` due to the `i < 3 && bs[i]` expression. So in the first iteration itself the loop sees the `false` value in the array and it exits as `i < 3 && bs[i]` is becoming `false` so nothing is printed.

There is no way to skip an iteration in the exit check in the for loop, you can either use an `if` as per your first snippet and conditionally print or you can use `continue` to skip an iteration depending on the value you get from the supplied array:

```js
const bs = [false, true, false];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if(bs[i] === false){
     //skips this iteration
     continue;
  }
  console.log('Hi', i);
}
```

You can also use the `forEach` method of an array:

```js
const bs = [false, true, false];

bs.forEach((o,i) => o !== false && console.log("Hi", i));
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks alright! The second parameter of a for loop tells the interpreter about when to stop the loop. In the first for loop, the loop continues until **i reaches 3**, while in the second loop, the loop immediately cuts off since the **first condition returns** false and indicates the interpreter to stop.